# Django development server on Raspberry Pi refuses connection

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian, django

I have a simple web service running on my Raspberry Pi, using the Django development server (manage.py runserver). I know it's working, because when I run `curl localhost:8000` on the Pi, I get the HTML contents of my website. When I run `netstat -tnl` on the pi, I get the following:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

However, when I try to connect to the website from a different computer on the same local network as the Pi (using `http://<local IP of the pi>:8000`), I get `connection refused`. (I've tried both `curl` and a web browser.)

I connect to the Pi exclusively through SSH, and things like `curl http://www.google.com` work, so I know the Pi is connected to the network.

I have the most recent version of Raspbian on the Pi. (I just reinstalled it yesterday thinking that might fix this issue)

How can I connect to this website? Do I need to open a port on the Pi or something?

I am not interested in connecting to this web server outside of my local network, so I don't think I should have to deal with port forwarding.

Comment: Try the following command to start your server: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Wow, that immediately fixed it. Why did that work? Oh, and would you please make that an answer so I can accept it? Thank you!

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the Django development servers is bound to 127.0.0.1 as you can see in the *Local Address* field. It means that it only accepts connections from your Pi.

When you use *0.0.0.0* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)), it is like a wildcard, it means that everyone on your local network can access it.

So in order to access your server from another machine you need to run the following command: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.